# How to connect public schema to restore backup in pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to restore a postgresql database backup file of power outage information sent by a work colleague and keep running into an error. They sent a file with a .backup extension and said "it should restore to the public schema of an empty postgresql database". I am using pgAdmin 4 and following the steps suggested here https://o7planning.org/11913/backup-and-restore-postgres-database-with-pgadmin to restore the database of

1. creating a new empty database
2. right clicking on the new database and clicking restore
3. linking to file path of backup and running

however, each time I get the error
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "outage_data" does not exist

Not sure how to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
(Not sure if it is important but I am running on Windows 10 and pgAdmin4 version 6)

Comment: How exactly was the dump taken? Ask. Also, ask for instructions how to restore. That's better than having us try to divine that information.

Comment: It seems the backup was *not*  taken from the "public" schema, but a schema named `outage_data`. Did you try to create a schema with that name before starting the restore?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get more errors after that?  This might be a harmless error.

For example, if a table in "public" references a table in "outage_data", but only public was dumped, then you will get this error when it tries to recreate the foreign key constraint.  That constraint of course will be missing, but no other harm is done.  The public table and all of its data will still be there.